# Не могу стереть в консоли Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, клавиатура, командная-строка

На Windows 10 в командной строке подключаюсь к виртуальной машине, работающая на Ubuntu, по SSH.

Подключение происходит удачно, а потом, когда пытаюсь стереть что-либо (нажимаю Backspace) -  то в консоли пишется ^H, нажимаю Delete - пишется  ^[[3~. И все клавиши с F1 по F12 и Esc тоже не работают :(

Как это исправить?

(если подключиться через ubuntu, то все работает)

Comment: А `ctrl+H` если нажать?

Comment: Линуксовые терминалы при помощи своей особой уличной магии умеют определять, какой сигнал отправлять для удаления символов, вот скриншот: https://imgur.com/2h6WFkA.png А ваш виндовый видимо не настроен, либо не умеет. Попробуйте другой. Насколько я помню, кроме cmd в винде есть ещё power shell.

Comment: что выводит `$ echo $TERM`?

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf, влево двигается курсор в power shell, а в cmd ^H (тоже самое что и Backspace)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, xterm-256color в cmd, cygwin в power shell

Comment: А если подключится через PuTTY или TeraTerm, результат такой же?